# How to calculate mean absolute error using cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, error

When I use 5-k cross validation, is the mean absolute error (MAE) equal to

$$\text{mean}(\text{MAEs of each 5 steps})=\frac{1}{5}(MAE_1 + \cdots + MAE_5)$$

or equal to

$$\text{mean}(\text{absolute errors of all predictions})$$?

Comment: If there are an even number of training examples, wont this be exactly the same? With an odd number then they differ slightly.

Comment: @B_M How does that work?  Perhaps you are thinking of medians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CV is a simulation of running testing algorithm on unseen data, so the first one.
The second is more an OOB error approximation of a bagging ensemble of your classifiers.

Comment: Indeed, it makes more sense.
http://wikidoc.org/index.php/Cross-validation : "The K results from the folds then can be averaged (or otherwise combined) to produce a single estimation"